# LocalDateTime Java - Get same day of week for next month

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, datetime

I have a date and a time of a month, for example `31/01/2020 at 14:00:00`, this is the last friday of January. How can I get the date for the last Friday of Feb, March, etc.? It should be dynamic because any date can come in, like the second Tuesday of any month and so on.

I am trying with the following with no luck:

```
LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 31, 14, 0, 0);

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(startTime.getYear(), startTime.getMonthValue() - 1, startTime.getDayOfMonth(), startTime.getHour(), startTime.getMinute(), startTime.getSecond());

int ordinal = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
startTime = startTime.plusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(ordinal, startTime.getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(startTime);
```

it's printing `06/03/2020 (six of march) at 14:00:00` which is wrong and should be `28/02/2020`

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a month, then adjust the date to get the last friday of the month: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-. Stop using the old, ugly Calendar class.

Comment: @JBNizet it can be any day of the month not just last friday. It can be first monday, third saturday, etc

Comment: That requirement is unrealistic. Suppose I'm the fourth Monday of the month. It's also the last Monday for that month. Now suppose I want the next "similar day" of the next month. Should I pick the 4th Monday, or the last Monday? If the month happens to have 5 Mondays, that's not the same day.

Comment: If you *know* that what you want is the last Monday, then use an adjuster that gives you the last Monday. If you *know* that you want the 4th Monday, then use an adjuster that gives you the 4th Monday. Those would be two different adjusters.

Comment: Your Question is not clear, and could use some rewriting. In particular, the "last Friday" is not the same kind of thing as an ordinal "4th Friday" or "5th Friday".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned before, there is some ambiguity in which day of the week of the month you mean, that is, whether you mean the *n*th day of week or the last *n*th day of week of the month.

One such example is Monday, February 24th, 2020. It is the fourth and last Monday of February 2020. If you are going to try to determine this for March 2020, which Monday would you pick? The fourth Monday is 23 March, but the last Monday is 30 March.

So apparently, you'll need to distinguish between whether you count forward or backward.

You could, for instance, create a class which represents a certain day of week in a month. This holds three fields: a day-of-week, a position, and whether the position is backwards or not. E.g.

- *"The second Monday of the month"* would have

  ```
  dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.MONDAY
  position = 2
  backwards = false
  ```

  and
- *"The last Thursday of the month"* would have

  ```
  dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.THURSDAY
  position = 1
  backwards = true
  ```

```
public class WeekdayInMonth {

    private final boolean backwards;

    private final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    private final int position;

    private WeekdayInMonth(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int position, boolean backwards) {
        if (position < 1 || position > 5) {
            throw new DateTimeException("Position in month must be between 1 and 5 inclusive");
        }
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        this.position = position;
        this.backwards = backwards;
    }
}
```

We could add factory methods to create `WeekdayInMonth`s from `LocalDate`s:

```
public static WeekdayInMonth of(LocalDate date) {
    int positionInMonth = (date.getDayOfMonth() - 1) / 7 + 1;
    return new WeekdayInMonth(date.getDayOfWeek(), positionInMonth, false);
}

private static WeekdayInMonth ofReversing(LocalDate date) {
    int lastDayOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).getDayOfMonth();
    int positionInMonth = (lastDayOfMonth - date.getDayOfMonth()) / 7 + 1;
    return new WeekdayInMonth(date.getDayOfWeek(), positionInMonth, true);
}
```

At last, we add a method to get a `LocalDate` from a `YearMonth` adjusted to the WeekdayInMonth.

```
public LocalDate toLocalDate(YearMonth yearMonth) {
    // Get a temporal adjuster to adjust a LocalDate to match a day-of-the-week
    TemporalAdjuster adjuster = this.backwards ? TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(this.dayOfWeek) : TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(this.dayOfWeek);

    int weeks = this.position - 1;
    LocalDate date = yearMonth.atDay(1)
            .with(adjuster)
            .plusWeeks(this.backwards ? 0 - weeks : weeks);
    if (!Objects.equals(yearMonth, YearMonth.from(date))) {
        throw new DateTimeException(String.format("%s #%s in %s does not exist", this.dayOfWeek, this.position, yearMonth));
    }
    return date;
}
```

**Working example**

[Here a working example at Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q2Qcgy).

---

#### Addendum

> I am getting errors like this if the initial date is Jan 1 2020: java.time.DateTimeException: FRIDAY #5 in 2020-02 does not exist. How could I get the previous weekday in case this happens? In this case, how would I get the previous Friday?

Well, then you need to adjust your LocalDate so that it falls within the specified yearmonth. Since every month has at least four day-of-the-weeks and no more than five of them, the difference is never more than a week. We could, after removing the `throw new DateTimeException` line, simply adjust the returned LocalDate using `plusWeeks`.

I've [forked the abovementioned example](http://ideone.com/EiyDxK) and added the `toAdjustingLocalDate` method.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed in a forward version, but its cool having it backwards too!

Comment: I am getting errors like this if the initial date is Jan 1 2020: java.time.DateTimeException: FRIDAY #5 in 2020-02 does not exist

Comment: @Wrong That is completely logical, since February never has more than four Fridays. You'll need to handle that exception.

Comment: how could i get the previous weekday incase this happens? In this case, how would I get the previous friday?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is kind of complicated but this is because "last of" or "third in" etc aren't always well defined and might not even exists under some conditions. So here is a solution that looks at the initial date and depending of the day of the month it either performs calculations from the start of the month, calculating forward, or the end of the month, calculating backwards.

From my testing it seems to generate the right results and I am sure some code refactoring could be done as well to improve the code but I leave that for the reader.

```
public static LocalDateTime nextWithSameDayOfMonth(LocalDateTime indate) {
    if (indate.getDayOfMonth() < 15) {
        return getForStartOfMonth(indate);
    } 

    return getForEndOfMonth(indate);
}

private static LocalDateTime getForEndOfMonth(LocalDateTime indate) {
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = indate.getDayOfWeek();
    LocalDateTime workDate = indate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    int count = 0;
    while (workDate.isAfter(indate)) {
        count++;
        workDate = workDate.minusWeeks(1);
    }

    LocalDateTime nextDate = indate.plusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    while (nextDate.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
        nextDate = nextDate.minusDays(1);
    }

    return count == 0 ? nextDate : nextDate.minusWeeks(count - 1);
}

private static LocalDateTime getForStartOfMonth(LocalDateTime indate) {
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = indate.getDayOfWeek();
    LocalDateTime workDate = indate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
    int count = 0;
    while (workDate.isBefore(indate)) {
        count++;
        workDate = workDate.plusWeeks(1);
    }

    LocalDateTime nextDate = indate.plusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
    while (nextDate.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
        nextDate = nextDate.plusDays(1);
    }

    return count == 0 ? nextDate : nextDate.plusWeeks(count - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the function work for you?

```
public class FindSameDayNextMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Next month of 'today' is " + FindSameDayNextMonth.getSameDayNextMonth());
    }

    public static Date getSameDayNextMonth() {
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, dt.getMonthValue()-1);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dt.getDayOfMonth());
        c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        return c.getTime();
    }
}
```

**The output is**
Next month of today is Mon Sep 23 07:18:09 CDT 2019

Comment: No need to mix the terrible legacy `Calendar` class with the modern *java.time* classes. Use only *java.time*.

Comment: This answer is certainly leading astray. When you can use the modern `LocalDateTime`, there is no reason whatsoever to introduces the poorly designed and long outmoded `Calendar` class. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, offers all the functionality you need.