# Get last and first day using Java

Tags: java, dayofweek, date

I have a requirement which is as follows: for example if today is Sunday then I need to get first Sunday and last Sunday in next month, and so on for all days in the week. I need to get the first and last day in next month.

Any idea on how I can do it

Is there a generic way to do it, or do I need to deal with each day separately? I have tried many ways, but all I found is each day has a special formula.

The technology I am using is Java.

Comment: Maybe duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625854/localdatetime-java-get-same-day-of-week-for-next-month

Comment: It’s related and a helpful link, @ElyasHadizadeh, thank you. I don’t consider it an exact duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question has got a couple of downvotes, that’s usual for new users here. It takes a bit to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And we’re picky. I didn’t downvote. I think the downvotes in this case are probably because you haven’t shown any attempt to search for a solution or any other effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE: dd-MM-yyyy");

    System.out.println("Now " + now.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("First " + getFirstDayOfNextMonth(now).format(dtf));
    System.out.println("Last " + getLastDayOfNextMonth(now).format(dtf));
}

public static LocalDate getLastDayOfNextMonth(LocalDate localDate) {
    return localDate
            .plusMonths(1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(localDate.getDayOfWeek()));
}


public static LocalDate getFirstDayOfNextMonth(LocalDate localDate) {
    return localDate
            .plusMonths(1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(localDate.getDayOfWeek()));
}
```

Output:

```
Now Sun: 03-05-2020
First Sun: 07-06-2020
Last Sun: 28-06-2020
```

Comment: What if first/last day *is* the given weekday? You need to use the `xxxOrSame` versions.

Comment: Hi , thanks for help , but i have question how i can add the java.time.localdate in EJB application ?

Comment: @DesrtRose Which is your Java version? For Java 8 or later `import java.time.LocalDate;`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Java 8 Time API, you need to use [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html), e.g. like this:

```java
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = today.getDayOfWeek();
LocalDate nextMonth = today.plusMonths(1);
LocalDate first = nextMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(dayOfWeek));
LocalDate last = first.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(dayOfWeek));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d, uuuu");
System.out.println(today.format(fmt));
System.out.println(first.format(fmt));
System.out.println(last.format(fmt));
```

*Output*

```
Sun, May 3, 2020
Sun, Jun 7, 2020
Sun, Jun 28, 2020
```

Answer (score -1):

i think, you can just continue with adding today's date with 7 day and go on.
İt would be generic.

for example:

get date : 03.05.2020 sunday

add 7 day to it, 10.05.2020 (is it on next month? no, son add another 7)

17.05.2020 (is it on next month? no, son add another 7)

etc.

You can easily do this adding things with Date interface

Comment: While the basic idea is fine, I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. One, it’s a poorly designed and long outdated class; two, it won’t work for the job, at least not unless you twist its arms harder on its back than it can tolerate.